# Step by step copy paste tutorial for configuring VNC/RDP without a reboot

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vnc

I have an existing ssh connection between my computer (A:12.04) and a remote computer (B:10.04) (from A I just type ssh B). I have root access on both. Both use ubuntu desktop edition. I am struggling to set up a remote desktop solution. After a lot of different software and tries, the closest I got was to be able to connect to the vnc server with vinagre, but the screen remained black, for an unknown reason.

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 12.04 with unity 3d on A, and ubuntu 10.04 with gnome on B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the setup I have working in VMs:

A:12.04 Desktop i386, Unity2d and 3d both tested, client, xvnc4viewer
B:10.04 Desktop i386, standard GNOME, server, x11vnc, openssh-server

From out of the box fully updated with nothing new installed

On A:
`sudo apt-get install xvnc4viewer`

On B:
`sudo apt-get install x11vnc openssh-server`

Now on A:
*first terminal:*
`ssh -t 192.168.1.1 'x11vnc -localhost -display :0'`
starts the x11vnc server

*second terminal:*
`xvnc4viewer -via 192.168.1.1 127.0.0.1:0`
connects the viewer

*verification it's only on port 22:*
`netstat -an | grep *insert far end ip address here*`
[image]

You should get results like that--^