# x11vnc login screen is blank

Tags: ssh, login, vnc

I have ssh access to an Ubuntu 16.04 box and I am normally able to connect, via `x11vnc`, using `-display :0 -connect [server.tld]`. It isn't a headless system and this only seems to work when there is someone logged in. When the machine is at the login screen, however, the vnc screen is black, with a cursor. I have tried

```
sudo x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display :0 -forever 
-bg -connect [server.tld]
```

but it doesn't make a difference. The screen is still black, with a cursor. How do I connect from the login screen?

Comment: have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/159303/step-by-step-copy-paste-tutorial-for-configuring-vnc-rdp-without-a-reboot/159758#159758

Comment: Same thing... The VNC desktop is:  localhost:0 PORT=5900 When I connect in, it just gives me a black screen and cursor.

Answer (score 1):

`light-locker` switches to `:1` when locking, so that explains why the vnc server running on `:0` only sees a black screen.

The workaround is simply to start another vnc server at `:1`, connect to it, enter password, and go back to the original vnc connection at `:0`

```
x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/\:1 -display :1
```